# How do I bring the chosen value to the top of a DropDownList?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to save in the dropdown the value choosed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761498/how-to-save-in-the-dropdown-the-value-choosed)

I have a `GridView` and a column with a `DropDownList` instead of `TextBox`.  The drop down has 2 values (1.No, 2.Yes).

The problem is, I can only choose the value "Yes". The code behind works for good for yes and I also added for value No.

And another thing is if I choose a value ("Yes", for example), how can I bring it to the top of the `DropDownList`, because it's always showing the default value (the value "No").

Comment: use selectedindex=1 to show value yes.

Comment: yep it worked now how can I save the value? if I choose something on update I want the dropdown to have the value choosed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
 <!--Add other attributes as you need to the grid view-->
 <!--NOTE: **OnRowDataBound="GridView_RowDataBound"** -->
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
       OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
 <Columns>

   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Dropdown Column">
       <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlYesNo" runat="server">
              <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="No"></asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Yes"></asp:ListItem>
          </asp:DropDownList>
       </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
   <!-- OTHER COLUMNS -->
 </Columns>
 <!-- REST OF THE STUFF -->
```

**CODE BEHIND**

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlYesNo");
        ddl.SelectedValue = 
          ((System.Data.DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem) ["dataColName"].ToString();

    }
 }
```

Comment: what this does?    ddl.SelectedValue = 
          ((System.Data.DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem) ["dataColName"].ToString();
 checks if the selected value is "dataColName" I need to replace dataColName with?

Comment: That is the name of the column you save ddl.SelectedValue when updating the database. If you need the updated value to be selected, then you need to assign that value back to the dropdown list control. That is what it is doing. Make sense?

Comment: well , On update I want the value choosed to be visible in the cell

Comment: @InziIrina Use SelectedValue=<%# Bind("ColumnName")%> in your dropdownlist.