# How to save in the dropdown the value choosed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

- I have a simple gridview and a column with dropdownlist.

  - The dropdownlist is containing 2 values : Yes/No.
  - If I choose Yes //my code will execute but always the No value is at
    the top and I can't choose it .

How can I make if I choose Yes , the value to be saved in the dropdown everythime I click edit ?

I know I asked once and I used if selected value = 0 ( Yes ) //my code will execute but it's not bringing Yet at the top ,

```
 DropDownList id = (DropDownList)sender;
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[GridView1.EditIndex];
            if (id.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                ((BoundField)GridView1.Columns[5]).ReadOnly = false;
                ((BoundField)GridView1.Columns[6]).ReadOnly = false;
            }
            if (id.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
               ((BoundField)GridView1.Columns[5]).ReadOnly = true;
                ((BoundField)GridView1.Columns[6]).ReadOnly = true;
            }
```

Comment: done , the code is added , the problem is that is always bringing the No at the top and if I press edit then update without changing anything , my columns are read only..and I want to bring the yes value at the top

Comment: where do you call this code (in which life cycle stage)?

Comment: in dropdownlist event : index changed

Comment: Why? There's no one who could help me as i can see

Comment: Please do not repost the [same questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9759292/861565) more than once.

Comment: not sure i understand.. show me gridview code.. why are we in dropdownlist event.. aren't you want to update the row or something?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set data source for dropdownlist only once on GET request. This issue happens cause you set data source everytime and you didn't persist selected item information.

```
 protected override OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Ddl.DataSource = new DataSource();
            DdlIssues.DataBind();
        }
    }
```